# Extracting Data from Excel Cells Derived from Complex Calculations Across Multiple Sheets

Tags: javascript, c#, excel-formula, openxml, closedxml

I'm encountering a challenge in extracting data from an Excel cell that derives its value from complex calculations spanning multiple sheets. The data source involves calculated fields from various tables, making the extraction process intricate. How can I efficiently extract this data? Specifically, I need to retrieve information from an Excel cell whose value originates from calculated fields across different sheets. Any insights or methods to streamline this extraction process would be greatly appreciated.

I've experimented with **OpenXML**, **Close XML**, and **JavaScript libraries** for data extraction. While these tools effectively retrieve data from straightforward formulas and text, they struggle when confronted with large and intricate Excel formulas, often resulting in **"#Num"** errors as output.

Comment: Please show some thing like what you have tried